# Fancybox2 image gallery that spans multiple pages

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

Is it possible to use fancybox-2 with image galleries that span multiple pages? It works fine for me when the image thumbnails are all on a single page, but for some galleries I have far too many images to reasonable list them all on a single page, so they are split up onto multiple pages with pagination links at the bottom. What I would like to do is if someone clicks on an image it opens in fancy box like normal; when they use the previous/next arrows the previous/next image shows like normal. If they are on the last image on the page, clicking the next arrow would show the first image from the next page (conversely, viewing the first image and clicking previous would show the last image from the previous page).

As an example, imagine an image gallery with 20 photos, 10 being shown on each of 2 pages. If the user is viewing image number 10 and clicks next, image 11 from page 2 would show. If the user is viewing image 11, clicking previous would show image 10 from page 1.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Using only jQuery plugins? No.

Comment: Consider infinite scroll to load more images into the page rather than going to another page. This would allow what you are imagining with fancybox. A little google search and you may find some code to imagine with

Comment: you may need to build the full gallery (all pages) in a javascript object or json file. from there it would be much easier to browse the whole gallery from any page.